# Dividing lines not appearing in KaTeX

Tags: markdown, katex

Just started using Gitlab Flavored Markdown (GFM) and experienced an interesting problem.

When I try using `\frac` in KaTeX, I see that the fraction line disappears sometimes when I type this:

````
```math
\frac{\partial u}{\partial K}
```
````

**Result:**

[image: result of the example above, no dividing line is shown]

Any ideas why it might be happening?

Comment: Which Markdown implementation are your using?

Comment: I am using GitLab Flavored Markdown (GFM).

Comment: Markdown doesn't have "math mode". I don't think GFM does, either. Are you using any other third-party tools, like MathJax?

Comment: GFM supports KaTex: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/markdown.html#math

Comment: Update: just noticed that it happens on Chrome but not on Safari, so probably a browser issue rather than GFM or KaTex

Comment: Ah, I misread earlier. In my experience "GFM" most frequently means Git​_Hub_, not Git​_Lab_, Flavored Markdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed a Chrome/KaTeX bug, as described in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/Khan/KaTeX/issues/824).

The solution for it is to **change the inline font size** in KaTeX. I found that it works fine with `\small` and `\huge`.

**Example:**

````
```math
\small\frac{\partial u}{\partial K}
```
````

**Result:**

[image]